# exec.Command with cp exits with status 1

Tags: go, exec

```
util.ExecuteCommandWithOuput(exec.Command("cp", "-r", "./*.json", artifact.dir))

func ExecuteCommandWithOuput(cmd *exec.Cmd) {
    output, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("Error executing ", cmd.Args, err)
    }
    fmt.Print(string(output))
}
```

Output

```
2017/01/16 13:26:35 Error executing [cp -r ./*.json myartifact] exit status 1
```

Questions

1. How do i get details of complete error message on failure of cp
   command ? I did have err != nill and Print err
2. Does exec.Command not support copy of files and recursive copy of directories ?
3. Any suggestions how i implement copy of files and recursive copy of
   directories ?

I have just started adopting Go and hence a new comer with Go.

Comment: Asked and answered also [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/owTRsLVg_8o/discussion).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do wild cards in `exec.Command`.  I'd iterate through the files in the directory and check if the extension ends in `.json` and then copy that file.

Answer (score 1):

### The problem

To explain: the so-called "wildcards" are expanded by the shell in which you typically execute command-line commands. That is, when you invoke `cp -r ./*.json dir/`, the shell kicks in, expands `*.json` by itself—producing a list of names of the files matching that pattern and located in the current directory and pass the `cp` command *a list* of such names.

So if you have, say, 10 matching files, the actuall call to `cp` will end up looking like

```
cp -r file1.json file2.json ... dir/
```

When you pass call `cp ...` directly—without the shell kicking in and expanding that `*.json` "fileglob" for you, the `cp` command receives the name of a file "*.json" verbatim and attempts to open it.  Since the file named exactly "*.json" supposedly does not exist, `cp` fails and exits.

### The solutions

The first (admittedly lame) solution is to pass a call to `cp` "through" a shell.  That is, turn your call to `cp` into a shell script and pass it to a shell.

The simplest way to do this is to use something like

```
exec.Command(`/bin/sh -c 'cp -r ./*.json manifest'`)
```

This will call a shell `/bin/sh` and pass it the script to execute via its `-c` command-line option.

Another solution is to roll copying yourself using the standard Go library: the functions of the `path/filepath` package provide support for both expanding fileglobs as the shell would do it and iterating over the entries of a given directory.  Using either of these approaches you can build the list of files to copy and/or iterate over them.

Then you can use the function `os.OpenFile()` to open the source and destination files, and `io.Copy()` to copy the contents between them.

Answer (score 0):

Using https://github.com/juju/utils/blob/master/fs/copy.go that internally uses io, os packages

Comment: That doesn't expand wildcards though, does it?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the arguments to bash needed to be split into separate parameters, but the cp command and its parameters need to be put into a single param of `exec.Command`, like so::

```
out, err := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", "cp -r ./*.json manifest").CombinedOutput()
```